# Inner Joining select statements to find next record by date

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, inner-join

I am stuck on trying to work out how to Inner Join a select statement to another select statement in order to return the next value for a specific item in date order.  I have a number of tables that identify a race meeting, race and race entrant and an initial select that identifies a participant who wins their first race.  Each race meeting contains multiple races and each race contains multiple entrants. I am using the participant unique identifier HorsePK in this instance to identify the records I need to return.  What I am then trying to achieve is to identify their result at their next race and the race after that but not anu subsequent races that may occur.  There will also be instances where the participant has only completed one race or 2 races and therefore these records should be excluded.

The initial select statement is:

```
Select RaceDate, HorsePK, HorseName, CareerRuns, FinishResult As ResultA

FROM [Punting].[dbo].[tblRace] 
        Inner Join tblRaceEntrant On tblRace.RacePK = tblRaceEntrant.RaceFK
        Inner Join tblRaceMeeting On tblRace.RaceMeetingFK = tblRaceMeeting.RaceMeetingPK
        Inner Join tblHorse On tblRaceEntrant.HorseFK = tblHorse.HorsePK
        Where CareerRuns < 1 And FinishResult = 1
```

This works fine and returns the records I expect.  My problem comes when I try to perform an inner join on a second statement and I think the problem is because I only want the next record for this participant in date order.  I think the Syntax is meant to be similar to:

```
Select RaceDate, HorsePK, HorseName, CareerRuns, FinishResult As ResultA, ResultB

FROM [Punting].[dbo].[tblRace] t
        Inner Join tblRaceEntrant On t.RacePK = tblRaceEntrant.RaceFK
        Inner Join tblRaceMeeting On t.RaceMeetingFK = tblRaceMeeting.RaceMeetingPK
        Inner Join tblHorse On tblRaceEntrant.HorseFK = tblHorse.HorsePK
        Inner Join (Select Top (1) FinishResult As ResultB
            FROM [Punting].[dbo].[tblRace] t1
                    Inner Join tblRaceEntrant On t1.RacePK = tblRaceEntrant.RaceFK
                    Inner Join tblRaceMeeting On t1.RaceMeetingFK = tblRaceMeeting.RaceMeetingPK
                    Inner Join tblHorse On tblRaceEntrant.HorseFK = tblHorse.HorsePK 
                    Order By RaceDate Desc) On t.HorsePK = t1.HorsePK
        
        Where CareerRuns < 1 And FinishResult = 1
```

This returns the error 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'On'.' and references 'Order By RaceDate Desc) On t.HorsePK = t1.HorsePK'.  I really don't know why this is wrong or if it would even return the record that I am expecting, and this is where I need some assistance.

To compound this, I think I need to add another inner join to the nested inner join to get the third row for this participant also.  The final output I am trying to achieve would look something like:

```
RaceDate,HorsePK,HorseName,CareerRuns,ResultA,ResultB,ResultC 
2017-03-12,52352,Just Hifalutin,0,1,4,2
2018-01-02,52837,Daunting Duchess,0,1,1,8
2017-07-16,53319,Yurilla,0,1,9,3
2017-04-25,53427,Maria Elisa,0,1,4,1
```

I'm not particularly proficient in SQL server (obviously) but I believe this is a better method of returning these results than using cursors (which I know of but am not proficient in).  Is there another way that I should be doing this?

Rather than pasting the DDL for each of the tables involved as it is quite a bit of data, these are the edited versions of the tables where the horse ID is used:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblHorse](
    [HorsePK] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [HorseName] [nvarchar](250) NOT NULL,
    [SireFK] [int] NULL,
    [DamFK] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblRaceEntrant](
    [RaceEntrantPK] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [RaceFK] [int] NOT NULL,
    [EntrantNumber] [int] NOT NULL,
    [HorseFK] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Age] [int] NULL,
    [Gender] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [FinishResult] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Sample data for tblHorse looks like:

```
HorsePK HorseName   SireFK  DamFK
77447   Scorpius    739 15383
84803   One Job 777 633
84815   Hooroo Lads 132 9797
84841   Ingear  766 21204
84884   Platinum Euros  143 11723
84889   Cryptic Wonder  211 17758
84912   Tricky Gal  90  19918
108448  Grey Detective  278 17515
109291  Nostradam Man   1347    6955
109319  Piccadilly Waltz    9   29848
```

Sample code for tblRaceEntrant looks like:

```
RaceEntrantPK   RaceFK  EntrantNumber   HorseFK Age Gender  FinishResult
67  10635   14  77447   2   C   1
355 27  8   84803   2   F   1
694 66  8   84841   2   F   1
845 82  8   84815   2   G   1
1342    129 3   84884   2   G   1
1841    179 8   84889   2   G   1
2082    203 6   84912   3   M   1
5163    510 7   84841   2   F   3
5236    517 2   84815   2   G   10
8574    871 3   84889   2   G   2
10062   1026    1   84912   3   M   1
27640   2824    3   84912   4   M   2
36037   3673    5   84912   4   M   1
42829   4401    7   84912   4   M   1
49460   5110    1   84912   4   M   2
60466   6290    8   84841   3   F   14
62017   6453    11  77447   3   C   2
67086   6975    18  84841   3   F   8
71604   7450    10  77447   3   C   1
76138   7921    7   84841   3   F   5
77838   8102    1   77447   3   C   4
84153   8761    4   84841   3   F   2
85015   8843    4   77447   3   C   5
114210  11756   6   77447   2   C   7
505957  52335   10  84841   3   F   3
508693  52635   3   84889   3   G   1
511758  52943   15  84841   3   F   1
516101  53391   8   84884   3   G   1
518339  53625   1   84889   3   G   2
521441  53947   12  84841   3   F   3
537301  55557   4   84912   4   M   1
545700  56358   2   84912   4   M   6
561458  59583   11  84912   4   M   3
569822  60358   2   77447   3   G   2
572503  60587   4   84912   4   M   2
575946  60853   9   77447   3   G   8
580109  61296   9   77447   3   G   3
580253  61310   9   84912   4   M   7
587297  61953   6   77447   3   G   5
603412  63355   3   77447   4   G   10
608617  63805   9   84841   4   M   2
615265  64429   4   77447   4   G   2
618260  64741   3   77447   4   G   5
623080  65235   3   84912   5   M   1
625750  65507   3   108448  3   C   1
630404  65993   3   84912   5   M   5
635248  66478   4   109291  3   G   1
635604  66517   7   109319  3   0   1
635652  66522   7   108448  3   C   9
637189  66679   10  84912   5   M   5
638846  66857   5   109291  3   G   10
```

I tried modifying the outer select to Select t.HorsePK instead of Select HorsePK as suggested, but this did not resolve the error.

Answer (score 0):

you need to alias your subquery ("tx" in my example) and then join using this alias. Also since you want to join on t1.HorsePK you need to select it in the subquery.

```
Select RaceDate, HorsePK, HorseName, CareerRuns, FinishResult As ResultA, ResultB

FROM [Punting].[dbo].[tblRace] t
        Inner Join tblRaceEntrant On t.RacePK = tblRaceEntrant.RaceFK
        Inner Join tblRaceMeeting On t.RaceMeetingFK = tblRaceMeeting.RaceMeetingPK
        Inner Join tblHorse On tblRaceEntrant.HorseFK = tblHorse.HorsePK
        Inner Join (Select Top (1) FinishResult As ResultB, t1.HorsePK /* <-- select anything you need outside of this subquery */
            FROM [Punting].[dbo].[tblRace] t1
                    Inner Join tblRaceEntrant On t1.RacePK = tblRaceEntrant.RaceFK
                    Inner Join tblRaceMeeting On t1.RaceMeetingFK = tblRaceMeeting.RaceMeetingPK
                    Inner Join tblHorse On tblRaceEntrant.HorseFK = tblHorse.HorsePK 
                    Order By RaceDate Desc) tx On t.HorsePK = tx.HorsePK /* <-- Give an alias to you subquery and join on this alias*/
        
        Where CareerRuns < 1 And FinishResult = 1
```

Comment: I think the logic of this makes sense to me, but this returns the error "Invalid column name 'HorsePK'." for each reference to this field.  I broke the query down to a single select statement to ensure that the field is returned and that works fine, so I assume that the problem is to do with how it is being referenced in the queries.  It also returns "Ambiguous column name 'HorsePK' on the inner join statement 'On t.HorsePK = tx.HorsePK'.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Could you please edit your question and append the DDL of your tables and maybe some sample data?

Comment: The ambiguous column error may come from your outer select. Select t.HorsePK instead of Select HorsePK.